# GameOver Zeus and Cryptlocker Viruses

Tags: virus

I was wondering considering there are a lot of professional coders out there is there any counteraction for the GameOver Zeus and Cryptlocker viruses that have been all over the news?

I mean for after the virus has infected your computer, would a simple system restore work? (this is assuming that your bank details were not on the computer or could not be found and you are held to ransome).

Comment: Really the answer is "it depends on the infection". If you want to know about these specific ones, go look those malware up on Google and read about what they do, and you'll have your answer.  As-is this is off-topic for SU (IMO) since it's not about an actual problem, and is vague as all get out. :)

Comment: ah I wasn't sure that it was on topic the way I wanted it to sound was more in the example of being infected with either of these for instance would I be able to fix it with a system restore I haven't had a chance to research into these yet just with it being on the news I thought people might have a quick answer. I'll do more research thanks for the help though :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I usually look on malware sites for the files they execute or they need to run and just delete them from a linux live USB (one can even edit the windows register from there). Once in windows I run `adwcleaner` and everything's okay. But only if you're able to find their files. Otherwise you may need other kind of solutions.